# How to setup an external hard drive with bitlocker enabled to be easily accessible?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, bitlocker, ownership

I have an external hard drive with bitlocker enabled.

I also have 3 computers with Windows 10 (that supports bitlocker). I often work from one computer to the other ones. When I work on one of them, I always sync it with the hard drive first.

As I checked "automatically unlock" during the first unlocking procedure, the computers can unlock the hard drive automatically for any subsequent plugging the hard drive.

## Problem

When I unplug the hard drive from one computer and plug it to  one of two other ones, the unlocking is successful but I cannot access it with the following error.

[image]

To solve this issue, I have to take the ownership with my user account as follows:

[image]

After several seconds elapses, I also need to check the following that also takes several seconds to complete.

[image]

This procedure seems to be cumbersome for daily work.

## Question

Is there any way to make the bitlocked hard drive accessible on any computer without retaking the ownership?

Comment: Worth pointing out the default permissions on an external drive is by default not a specific user from a specific installation of Windows.  I can’t say, how it happened, but you experienced this issue because the ownership wasn’t configured in the way you describe in your answer. The default permissions should have been configured to a user group not a specific user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing many trial and errors, I found the solution.

Take the ownership with `Administrators` and  add permission with `Everyone` as follows.

[image]

Now the hard drive can be plugged to any computers without doing the cumbersome ritual explained above.